# How to redesign a recursive function calls to rather use parallel stream or futures or Executor service?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, parallel-processing, future

The below code makes recursive calls and it is taking time. I want to do reduce the time for this code.

```
private void traversePricingProductOffering(
                     List<IPricingProductOffering> pricingProductOfferings,
                     String customerID ) {

   if (pricingProductOfferings == null) {
       return;
   }

   pricingProductOfferings.forEach(
                           pricingProductOffering->{
                                  processPricingProductOffering(
                                         pricingProductOffering,
                                         customerID
                                         );
                               // here it process on list element
                               //      as well call external
                               //                   microservices for data.

                                 traversePricingProductOffering(
                                         pricingProductOffering.getPricingProductOffering(),
                                         customerID
                                         );
                           } );
   }
```

Some ideas are in my mind :

1. Use parallel stream.
2. Use Future and callable with Executor service.

Below problems, I can see :

1. As my application works in a docker container, which core processor gets used while in multithreading? The docker containers' or the host machine's one?
2. Parallel stream used fork-join and it uses multi-thread internally and same for Executor service.
3. The method `processPricingProductOffering(pricingProductOffering, customerID);` calls external services and updates the `pricingProductOffering`. If I go for future or parallel stream, how this updated object gets passed to every thread.

Comment: Docker does not have cores, it's just an abstraction layer over the host OS. By default all host cores will be used and you can limit it per container using the `--cpuset-cpus` parameter. As for the usage of parallel streams - generally it plays bad with IO, so you'd better off using a `CompletableFuture.runAsync(task, executor)` with your own executor and chain both processPricingProductOffering and traversePricingProductOffering one after another inside your `forEach` like: `runAsync(task1).thenRun(task2).join()`

Comment: One question, how can a modified objects gets used for the successive calls in the above approach?processProductOffering method updates the product object after iteration.

Comment: It's not exactly the same object as your recursive call is made with a "shallow" list of offerings  `traversePricingProductOffering(pricingProductOffering.getPricingProductOffering())` which is then enriched inside and the cycle repeats for child lists again, so that each "enrichment" is done against a child list separately. At the end you have the entire tree enriched.